# Create sequence based on a condition

Tags: r

How to conditionally increment if the previous value is greater than the current value? Say I have a column x on my data frame and I want a column y which starts from 1 and increments if the previous value is greater than the current.

```
x   y
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
1   3
2   3
5   3
```

Comment: Look at `diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 mentioned, you can use `cumsum` with `diff` to generate `y`.

```
cumsum(diff(x) < 0) + 1
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

You might want to prepend 1 in the beginning to get `y` with same length as `x`.

```
c(1, cumsum(diff(x) < 0) + 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

**data**

```
x <- c(1:6, 1:8, 1, 2, 5)
```

Comment: @Sathish it depends on what you mean by "work". It will work exactly for the case where you want a running total of the times the vector decreases. Which is what the OP asked for.